# Getting a "missing } inserted" error when I can't find a mismatch

Tags: errors

I've got

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
E(W_n | W_{n-1}, \ldots , W_0) &= E\right(\frac{Z_{n}}{m_{n}} | \frac{Z_{n-1}}{m_{n-1}}, \ldots , \frac{Z_{0}}{m_{0}}\left) \\
    &= \frac{1}{m_n} \mu_n Z_{n-1} = \frac{Z_{n-1}}{m_{n-1}} \\
    &= W_{n-1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which gives me the compile error

```
Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
} l.135 \end{align*}
```

but it seems to look fine. I checked all my brackets and I couldn't find a mismatch. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: You have `\left` and `\right` switched.

Comment: Well, `\left` is at the left and `\right` is at the right. `;-)`

Comment: Well, yeah, but why does that get flagged as an error about braces?

Comment: Because LaTex is weird, man

Comment: @mathers101 You make a strong argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have `\right( ... \left)`: they must be the other way around.

I did some other refinements, such as `\mid` instead of `|` and `\;\middle|\;` where the bar should follow the bigger parentheses. Also `\dots` should be used instead of `\ldots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
E(W_n \mid W_{n-1}, \dots , W_0) &= E\left(\frac{Z_{n}}{m_{n}} \;\middle|\; \frac{Z_{n-1}}{m_{n-1}}, 
  \dots , \frac{Z_{0}}{m_{0}}\right) \\
    &= \frac{1}{m_n} \mu_n Z_{n-1} = \frac{Z_{n-1}}{m_{n-1}} \\
    &= W_{n-1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `\;\middle|\;`! What's the difference between `\dots` and `\ldots`? I tried them both out and they looked the same to me.

Comment: @MissMonicaE The difference is that usually `\dots` is able to automatically choose the right variant between centered or low dots.

Comment: @egreg - I think something went wrong while pasting.